# non-square matrix

Tags: matrices

How to define a metric to say one non-square matrix greater than another non-square matrix?

If they are square matrices, it is easy. For example,
 $T_1$ and $T_2$ represent two square matrices. If we want to define $T_1 > T_2$, then we can say $T_1 - T_2>0$ which means ($T_1 - T_2$) is positive definite .

Comment: I ordinarily say a matrix must be symmetric to talk about positive-definiteness.

Comment: This is easy to accomplish: $T_1 > T_2$ if $(T_1)_{11} > (T_2)_{11}$. There we go! A nice partial order. Of course, it is probably worthless for whatever you want to do. And that is the point. In order to be useful, any definition has to fit some purpose, and you have said nothing about what purpose you want this one to serve. Figure out what that purpose is, and it will tell you how to define the order, or else tell you no such order is possible.